# Does throwing any exception cause the GAE instance to restart

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my code i have a lot of code like the following. I am wondering if it's a bad thing for my server and if it will cause the instance to restart.

```
if (opLoginId == loginId) {
      datastore.delete(key);
      return 0;
} else {
      throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless these are being caught at some higher level (say, to turn them into the right HTTP response), then yes, you're killing your instance.